# Commerce Paypal Confirm Pane missing

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I have installed Drupal Commerce with latest version and also [Commerce Paypal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) + [Commerce Paypal Express Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal_ec).

EC is working so far, but I can´t find the Confirm-Pane on the checkout page/configuration.

Can somebody give me a tip what to do to make it visible on the checkout configuration.

It should be visible under "Confirm Order" and its called:
 "Express Checkout review and confirm (only to be used on the confirm order page)"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...

I had a similar module installed (commerce_paypal_ec) and it was conflicting with commerce_paypal submodule for EC.

i misunderstood the concept, i tought i had to install submodules but those exist already in commerce_paypal.

in case somebody run into the same problem.

kind regards,
kevin